# Trying to save HTML5 canvas as image to server using the Yii framework

Tags: jquery, canvas, yii

I have been trying to figure this out for about a week and used several solutions found online. I have not been able to apply any of them to yii.

Here's the click function that has no problem firing once I click submit.

```
<script>

function saveDrawing() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
 $.post('<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("generator/save")? >', { imageData: canvas } );
}
</script>
```

I ran it through firebug, it seems as though it's not finding the URL where to process this request. I have tried several different URL parameters to get to the form processing page.

Here is the action in the Generator Controller its trying to find

```
 public function actionSave()
    {

        if(isset($_POST['imageData']))
        {
           $data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
            $decodedData = base64_decode($data);
            $model->image=$_POST['imageData'];
            $model->save();
            $fp = fopen(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/canvas.png', 'wb');
            fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
            fclose();
        }
       $this->render('save');


    }
```

Comment: do you get a 404 in firebug? did you check the url that is generated? is it the correct expected one?

Comment: no 404 error. the url is generated, i have used a few different ways to generate the url cause i believe somehow this is where the problem lies. after digging digging and more digging online, the way i have it here should work, but the image does not save to server

Comment: ok, so you think the client side is fine but server action is not working correctly?

Comment: I cant say for sure. After going back and forth making changes, Im not sure whats stopping it from executing the .post() correctly. Im kinda new to firebug, but understand it a little. When I step through the saveDrawing() it respond correctly, storing the canvas data in canvas, and i step over the .post() it store the parameters in a function() correctly, etc, but this is kinda where it losses me

Comment: if you haven't checked the _net_ tab or _console_ tab of firebug, then check those too, see that the post request is being done, if it is then we know that there is problem in server, else we know that problem is in client. Btw, i just noticed that you have a space between `? >` in the php closing tag (`$.post(...)`), is that just a typo here?

Comment: yes that is a typo here. Ok There is a couple of errors neither of which is no relation i can just remove its functionality.

Comment: It could be the path to the image. Try using getcwd() instead of baseUrl

Comment: You dont initialize `$model` in `actionSave()`? eg. `$model = new ImageRecord`.

Comment: @eskimo i think you on to something. When I used getcwd() the directories are not the same. It will be a few hours before i could make adjustments. I will report back later

Comment: I believe I now know whats causing it, but not sure how to fix. Info i got from and older post. the .post() is not working because headers are being sent along with it, headers that are generated in the framework somehow. How do I stop it? The older post said it was fixed, but didnt say how it was done.

Comment: can you update you question to your findings, because it has become unclear what you are asking now

Comment: Yes, please update question with all relevant code on both ends so we can reproduce and try to help.

Comment: try debuging without ajax and when the server side is working then use ajax, if found it easier, so you can do stuff like print_r($_POST) and things like that